# Strange '#filenames#' from emacs

Tags: unix, emacs, backup, autosave

So after I modify one of my source files in `emacs`, when I list the files in the directory, there is a copy of the one I just modified with `#` signs on either side of it.

Example:

```
$ cd utility/
$ ls
FRCUtility.java
$ emacs FRCUtility.java 
$ ls
#FRCUtility.java#  FRCUtility.java
```

What does the `#` sign mean?  Should I delete the file or keep it?  A detailed explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The # signs are put in by emacs when it makes a temporary file. You can delete them if emacs doesn't do it for you.

Answer (score 4):

It's an autosave file. It's there so you don't lose your changes to the file if emacs or your computer crashes. It disappears when you save the file.